# Error in JNI call back

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

i am researching on JNI call backs

- i need to make a call from cpp to java

my sample code in cpp is as follows

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_arjunh_myapplication_MainActivity_getJniString(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF("This string comes from JNI");

jclass clazz = env->FindClass("MainActivity");  // Error at this line

jmethodID messageMe = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "messageMe", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");


jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(instance, messageMe, jstr);

const char* str = env->GetStringUTFChars((jstring) result, NULL);
printf("%s\n", str);

env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, str);


return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from JNI!");
}
```

my java class is as follows  ( MainActivity )

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getJniString();

        }
    });

}


public void messageMe(String text) {

    tv.setText(text);

}
```

the error is

```
 ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.arjunh.myapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.arjunh.myapplication-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.arjunh.myapplication-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

How to refer the class

jclass clazz = env->FindClass("MainActivity");

Answer (score 2):

I think you should specify package name as the [documentation suggest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html):

> name: a fully-qualified class name (that is, a package name, delimited
>   by “/”, followed by the class name). If the name begins with “[“ (the
>   array signature character), it returns an array class. The string is
>   encoded in modified UTF-8.

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("your/package/name/MainActivity")
```

Comment: my pakage is  com.example.martin.myapp soo it should be like jclass clazz = env->FindClass(" com.example.martin.myapp/MainActivity") ??

Comment: no, replace with '/', also see this http://www.mobileway.net/2015/03/20/android-pro-tip-call-java-methods-from-c-using-jni/

Comment: got it ... but i have an another error do i need to use the CallObjectMethod or CallVoidMethod ?

Comment: The `<type>` in `Call<type>Method` refers to the type returned by the method you're calling, not the type of its arguments.